# How can I display related data from SQLite in XAML for UWP apps?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Visual Studio debugging shows that I have successfully retrieved the data from the database. My database has two tables, with the Terms table containing a foreign key from the Years table, as seen below:

```
public class Term
{

    [Key]
    public int TermId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }


    public int YearId { get; set; }
    public Year Year { get; set; }
}

public class Year
{
    [Key]
    public int YearId { get; set; }
    public string YearName { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }

    public List<Term> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource YearDisplay}}">
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearId}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearName}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

How can I display a Year so that it contains all the Terms which reference it?

I've spent ages trying to figure this out, and I would really appreciate it if any help was given ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another GridView control (or ListView) for list of Terms:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource YearDisplay}}">
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearId}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearName}" />
            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Terms}">
               <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                     <!-- ..... -->
                  </DataTemplate> 
               </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```